# Python 3.4.2 loops not

Tags: python, list

t ask the user for input and when they type letters it comes up with an error message (as i want) but even when user enters number it comes up with error. I want it to come out of this loop and on to next for name if correct data is inputed.

Comment: Read the [input() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). That function always returns a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 5):

`input` always returns text - even there are only digits.

Use `int(Telephone)` to convert to integer or `Telephone.isdigit()` to check if there are only digits in text.

---

**BTW:** both methods are useless if user use spaces or `-` in phone number ;)

Maybe you will have to remove spaces and `-` using `replace()` before you use `int()` or `isdigit()`

Comment: OP, check out [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert to an int:

```
while True:
    try:
        Telephone = int(input("Please enter your telephone number "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Sorry, system does not recognise input ")
```

Comment: says invalid syntax for 'catch'

Comment: Even using this code and changing catch to except it runs and every time it runs the question just keeps repeating when it should move to next loop

Comment: take a look at the main question i added new bit its get confusing

Comment: @AChampion could you take a look